# Chrome-Extension: iterate through all tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

How would I iterate through all tabs a user has open and then check if they have a particular HTML item with `id = 'item'`?

Comment: Can you please update the chosen answer? The API is now deprecated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs){
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabs[i].id, { action: "xxx" });                         
  }
});
```

After that to look after your item, if you can make it like this :

```
document.getElementById('item')
```

Don't forget that you can't manipulate the HTML by using the "background page" So the first code snip is for the background page, and the second have to be on a content script ;)

Comment: You might want to add to check for the element he can send document.getElementById('item') != null and save that somewhere and retrieve it to determine if the element exists on the page.

Comment: Haha no problem, typing kinda slow today and had to refer to my extension to make sure what I was writing was correct.

Comment: The correct answer should be changed to  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15281976/257319

Comment: @Sindar, Why not just use **tabs.query** which gives you all tabs?

Comment: chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow is deprecated

Answer (score 79):

It appears this method has been deprecated in favor of `chrome.tabs.query`:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query

So now you'd want to do:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { /* blah */ } );
```

Passing an empty `queryInfo` parameter would return all of the tabs.

Comment: but how does this iterate over the tabs? Is there a length method for `tabs`? Most API methods take a single tab or tab property, so you'd need to index them with a variable like `tabs[0]...tabs[n]`. How to get n?

Comment: @jiggunjer, n = tabs.length, tabs - is an array

Comment: @Golden, What happens if you put the first arg as `null` instead of `{}`?

Comment: the new API reference URL is https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query

Answer (score 10):

##### Edit July 2022:

This answer was originally written for MV3 users. If you're looking for a MV2 answer, see above. Otherwise, this answer will work perfectly fine with MV3.

##### Original answer

`chrome.tabs.query` is the function you're looking for. You can pass in parameters to a object to filter the tabs. In your case, you want to iterate over all the open tabs. Here's two versions of the code you're looking for:

### Asynchronous callback version

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
    // do whatever you want with the tab
  });
});
```

### Promise version

```
var tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
  // do whatever you want with the tab
});
```

In both cases, the parameter `tab` is a [Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab).

Comment: var tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({}); does not work. It says, "Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback): No matching signature."

Comment: My comment above is for Manifest V2. It may work fine in Manifest V3.

Comment: I've updated the answer with relevant information for MV2 users!

Answer (score 2):

This is a not deprecated vanilla way (may 2019):

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
        tabs.forEach(tb => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tb.id, { action: "xxx" });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Maybe this worked back in May, but as of now, in October, it seems like you have to iterate through both the `{ highlighted: true }`, as in, the focused tab, and `{ hightlighted: false }` - all the other ones - to really go through them all.