# Cycle through tabs , Google Chrome extensions API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a slideshow extension for Google Chrome. I've created the code that fetches the right URLs and opens them in one tab each. Now I'm looking for a function in the Chrome extension API that will allow me to switch tabs programmatically, but I can't find one? Is there one and if not, what are my options?

Comment: You want to cycle through the tabs or switch tabs? I don't understand this question. The title is similar to ["Chrome-Extension: iterate through all tabs?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409242) but the question body makes it sound totally different `\-:`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Tabs API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)? The [`update()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) method allows you to select a tab like this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});
```

Comment: That's exactly the API I was looking at - and working with to create the new tabas - but I misread, I thought it could only update the URL. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that the property is now called `active`, not `selected`, although this still works for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The value `selected` has been deprecated. Use `highlighted` instead:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {highlighted: true});
```