# Get the urls of all the tabs in all windows using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Is this possible for chrome extension to get all the URLs in all tabs using chrome extension ?

I have got the url of current Tab using this code

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    tabUrl = tab.url;
    alert(tabUrl);
});
```

We need the following permissions in manifest.json file

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

My question is to find out the URLs in all tabs ?

Comment: For people who land here not trying to code an extension to do this but just want a quick way to do it manually: highlight all the tabs, save them all as bookmarks to a new folder, and then within Bookmark Manager, copy all of the bookmarks to your clipboard. Then paste into Notepad. https://www.howtogeek.com/723144/how-to-copy-the-url-addresses-of-all-open-tabs-in-chrome/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome-Extension: iterate through all tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409242/chrome-extension-iterate-through-all-tabs)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
  windows.forEach(function(window){
    window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      //collect all of the urls here, I will just log them instead
      console.log(tab.url);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do I need an extra permission here for windows ?

Comment: @BeardFist is `windows.forEach(...)` asynchronous?

Comment: Is this still the recommended way to get or the API deprecated?

Answer (score 21):

With [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) method, you can also simply do,

```
 chrome.tabs.query({},function(tabs){     
    console.log("\n/////////////////////\n");
    tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      console.log(tab.url);
    });
 });
```

Comment: In order for the URL to be accessible, one must have `"permissions": [ "tabs"]` in their `manifest.json` file

Comment: See also this [promise-based version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68787047/6243352).