# URLs of currently open tabs of a browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want all the URLs of currently open active of a browser to be captured and display it on a simple HTML page. Is this possible ?

is there any possibility in getting all URL's using any Script.

Regards,
Mahesh.

Comment: From a webpage in the browser? Not going to happen, nope nope nope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185044/get-the-urls-of-all-the-tabs-in-all-windows-using-chrome-extension